# how to access State in other component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how to access this state in another component?

I am using `functional Component`

[image]

Comment: See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and move the state into the closest common ancestor component. Please also include all code an formatted code snippets instead of as images. Images aren't searchable and are more difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are supposed to access the state In the several screens or components then we have to implement a global state by using Context API From React.

**check out the docs for more details:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

**Example of how to use context API to implement a global state.**

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-context-in-5-minutes/

Answer (score 1):

You can store value you want to access on a common parent as a state:

```
  const [commonValue, setCommonValue] = useState("get me anywhere");
```

Then pass the state and set state down to the children:

```
  <Child1 value={commonValue} setCommonValue={setCommonValue} />
```

When you want to change that value and reflect the change to other component, just call:

```
  props.setCommonValue("I changed");
```

Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-breeze-pheqo?file=/src/App.js:450-495